# Creating composite band image form multiple Sentinel 2 raster data using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, for-loop, data-management, composite

I have multiple Sentinel 2a raster images in separated folders at same location, which means every image is in separate folder. Now I want to create composite band of each raster. I have written a code and its given an error, its says
arcpy.CompositeBands_management(";".join([raster_blue,raster_green,raster_red,raster_nir,raster_swir_1,raster_swir_2]), output)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, Raster found

How do I specify arguments in composite band?

Here is the code

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.env.workspace = "L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\Satellite_image\\T44QPJ_20200405"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

input_raster = arcpy.ListRasters()
outputDir = "L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\Layer_stack"
print(input_raster)

for data in input_raster:
    blue = arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(data,
"L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\Satellite_image\\T44QPJ_20200405_B02_10m_blue.jp2", "", "", "1")
    green = arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(data,
"L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\Satellite_image\\T44QPJ_20200405T045651_B03_10m_green.jp2", "", "", "2")
    red = arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(data,
"L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\Satellite_image\\T44QPJ_20200405T045651_B04_10m_red.jp2", "", "", "3")
    nir = arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(data,
"L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\Satellite_image\\T44QPJ_20200405T045651_B08_10m_nir.jp2", "", "", "4")
    swir_1 = arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(data,
"L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\Satellite_image\\T44QPJ_20200405T045651_B011_20m_swir_1.jp2", "", "", "5" )
    swir_2 = arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(data,
"L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\Satellite_image\\T44QPJ_20200405T045651_B012_20m_swir_2.jp2", "", "", "6")

    raster_blue = arcpy.Raster("L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\Satellite_image\\T44QPJ_20200405_B02_10m_blue.jp2")
    raster_green = arcpy.Raster("L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\Satellite_image\\T44QPJ_20200405T045651_B03_10m_green.jp2")
    raster_red = arcpy.Raster("L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\Satellite_image\\T44QPJ_20200405T045651_B04_10m_red.jp2")
    raster_nir = arcpy.Raster("L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\Satellite_image\\T44QPJ_20200405T045651_B08_10m_nir.jp2")
    raster_swir_1 = arcpy.Raster("L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\Satellite_image\\T44QPJ_20200405T045651_B011_20m_swir_1.jp2")
    raster_swir_2 = arcpy.Raster("L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\Satellite_image\\T44QPJ_20200405T045651_B012_20m_swir_2.jp2")
    # the first part of the file name before extension (if present) then add *.img
    output = os.path.join(outputDir,os.path.splitext(data)[0].split('_')[0] + '.img')
arcpy.CompositeBands_management(";".join([raster_blue,raster_green,raster_red,raster_nir,raster_swir_1,raster_swir_2]), output)
```

please help me on this.

Comment: Composite bands accepts raster datasets--no need to convert to layer. Also the in raster parameter requires a python list. You are separating by ;. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/composite-bands.htm

Comment: As per you suggestion I made changes in code but it give error like thisRuntimeError: ERROR 000732: Input Raster: Dataset L:\Arcpy\Data\Satellite_image\T44QPJ_20200405_B02_10m does not exist or is not supported

Comment: You need to include an extension in your path.

Comment: You are still passing [raster objects](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/raster-object.htm) when it should be (accouring to the [help section](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/composite-bands.htm)): Mosaic Dataset ; Mosaic Layer ; Raster Dataset or Raster Layer. Raster object is something else

Comment: I added the extension but I got the same error.

Comment: arcpy.CompositeBands_management("raster_blue.jp2;raster_green.jp2;raster_red.jp2;raster_nir.jp2;raster_swir_1.jp2;raster_swir_2.jp2", output). Instated of the raster object I used raster layer but this time I got above error.

Comment: The code in your question still raster objects.

Comment: You mean I should use layer path in compositeband_management?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [code sample](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/composite-bands.htm) in the help section. In rasters should be one string with the rasters separated by semicolons:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\folder\with\all\raster\files"
arcpy.CompositeBands_management("band1.tif;band2.tif;band3.tif",
                                "compbands.tif")
```

Comment: I made changes in the last line as per you say. But some error is coming,arcpy.CompositeBands_management(";".join([raster_blue,raster_green,raster_red,raster_nir,raster_swir_1,raster_swir_2]), output)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, Raster found

Comment: I think it wants paths to rasters, not raster objects.

Comment: You mean that each bands path?

Comment: Yes like the code sample

Comment: arcpy.CompositeBands_management("L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\Satellite_image\\T44QPJ_20200405T045651_B02_10m_blue.jp2;L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\Satellite_image\\T44QPJ_20200405T045651_B03_10m_green.jp2;
    L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\Satellite_image\\T44QPJ_20200405T045651_B04_10m_red.jp2;
    L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\Satellite_image\\T44QPJ_20200405T045651_B08_10m_nir.jp2;
    L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\Satellite_image\\T44QPJ_20200405T045651_B011_10m_swir_1.jp2;
    L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\Satellite_image\\T44QPJ_20200405T045651_B012_10m_swir_2.jp2", output)

Comment: I try like this but is gives syntax error: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question in response to requests for clarification. It would make Python syntax errors more obvious.

Comment: I edit the above question.